# Can we prove, without invoking invariance of domain, that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Can we prove, without invoking invariance of domain, that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are not homeomorphic, or equivalently, that no open set of $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to an open set of $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. If they were, then $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ would be homeomorphic. This is a contradiction as $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ is connected but $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not.